# Using MouseUp event in wpf DataGrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, windows-forms-designer, mouseup

I have two tables: Requests and Items.
This MouseUp event is for WinForm DatagridRow.
 How use this event for WPF DataGrid?

```
private void gridRequests_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataBase db = new DataBase();
            try
            {
                s = gridRequests[0, gridRequests.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString();
                dt = db.MySelect("select * from Items where RequestID='" + s + "'");
                gridItems.DataSource = dt;
                gridItems.Columns[0].HeaderText = "No.";
                gridItems.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Item Code";
                gridItems.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Item Name";

            }
            catch { }
        }
```

I use this in wpf:

```
private void requestsDataGrid_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataBase db = new DataBase();
            s = requestsDataGrid[0, requestsDataGrid.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString();
            dt = db.MySelect("select * from Items where RequestID='" + s + "'");
        }
```

CurrentRow or CurrentCell is my error point.

Comment: OMG, sql query in UI and empty catch block, is this in production ? ahhh and concatenating sql query... did you hear about sql injection?

Comment: you can use same MouseUp event, what is the problem?

Comment: CurrentRow.Index or CurrentCell.Index is my error point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [DataGrid.SelectedIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and/or [DataGrid.SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.selecteditem%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) instead

Comment: I used: s = requestsDataGrid.SelectedIndex.ToString();

            dt = db.MySelect("select * from Items where RequestID='" + s + "'");
            requestsDataGrid.DataContext = dt; when I click Requests rows, all rows will hide!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Arsen,
I used this:

```
 private void requestsDataGrid_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataBase db = new DataBase();

                string s = requestsDataGrid.SelectedItem.ToString();

                dt = db.MySelect("select * from Items where RequestID='" + s + "'");
                gridItems.DataContext = dt;
                gridItems.Columns[0].HeaderStringFormat = "No";
                gridItems.Columns[1].HeaderStringFormat = "Item Code;
                gridItems.Columns[2].HeaderStringFormat = "Item Name";

        }
```

this common error: *Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'System.Data.DataRowView' to data type int.*